# CSHTML ASP code to read azure blob CSV file line by line

Tags: azure, razor, blobstore

How to load a CSV blob in line by line?

The code example below loads the entire blob into one string.

Ultimately I want to import the CSV blob into Azure SQL.

```
{ 
   // reference to my blob 

   var blobRef = "thecsvfiles/Test.csv";

   // gets the blob as text 
   var astring = WindowsAzureStorage.DownloadBlobAsText(blobRef);

   Response.Write (astring);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just loaded the entire file into a string then split on CR and Comma..

```
string csvData = WindowsAzureStorage.DownloadBlobAsText("thecsvfiles/DiskSpace.csv");


            foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n').Skip(1))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    int i = 1;
                    foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
                    {
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
```